# issue with php xmailer? I don't think it's syntax

Tags: html, forms, php

code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$staddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['staddress']);
$city = htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']);
$state = htmlspecialchars($_POST['state']);
$zipcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST['zipcode']);
$eventtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eventtype']);
$guests = htmlspecialchars($_POST['guests']);
$month = htmlspecialchars($_POST['month']);
$day = htmlspecialchars($_POST['day']);
$year = htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']);
$hourstart = htmlspecialchars($_POST['hourstart']);
$hourfinish = htmlspecialchars($_POST['hourfinish']);
$eventstreet = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eventstreet']);
$eventcity = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eventcity']);
$eventstate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eventstate']);
$eventzip = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eventzip']);
$howwereu = htmlspecialchars($_POST['howwereu']);
$custmsg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['custmsg']);
$date = date('m-d-Y');


$to = '' . $email . '';
$subject = 'Thanks,' .$name . ' for requesting a quote!';
$message = "We will contact you as soon as possible!  ";
$headers = 'From: no-reply@xxx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: xxx@xxx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$to2 = 'xxx@xxx.com';
$subject2 = '' . $name . ' has requested a quote!';
$message2 = '

<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here is the information provided. If the field is blank, the customer did not fill out the 
form.</p>
 <table>
<tr>
<td>Customer Name:</td>
<td>' . $name . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Email:</td>
<td>' . $email . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Phone:</td>
<td>' . $phone . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Street Address:</td>
<td>' . $staddress . '</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Customer City:</td>
<td>' . $city . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer State:</td>
<td>' . $state . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Zipcode:</td>
<td>' . $zipcode . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Type:</td>
<td>' . $eventtype . '</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td># of Guests:</td>
<td>' . $guests . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Month:</td>
<td>' . $month . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Day:</td>
<td>' . $day . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Year:</td>
<td>' . $year . '</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Event Start Hour:</td>
<td>' . $hourstart . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Finish Hour:</td>
<td>' . $hourfinish . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Street:</td>
<td>' . $eventstreet . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event City:</td>
<td>' . $eventcity . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event State:</td>
<td>' . $eventstate . '</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Event Zip:</td>
<td>' . $eventzip . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>How were you referred:</td>
<td>' . $howwereu . '</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Message:</td>
<td>' . $custmsg . '</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

';
$header2  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header2 .= 'From: no-reply@xxx.com' . "\r\n";
$header2 .= 'Reply-To: xxx@xxx.com' . "\r\n";
$header2 .= 'X-Mailer: PHP Version: 5.0+' . "\r\n";

mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $header2);

header('Location: http://www.xxxx.com');

?>
```

Does not send emails, and it used to. I'm wondering what changed? Maybe the hosting company updated php or something without me knowing? I'm really lost. Maybe I've just overlooked something, maybe syntax. I hope you all can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can confirm that it's not a syntax problem (checked with php -l) .. but I think you should try to avoid posting issues that might be caused by syntax errors :)

Comment: Maybe you could check to see if `mail()` returns true or false? Turn up [`error_reporting`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and see if any warnings are being generated? Check the mail logs on the server to see if the message was sent or not?

Comment: Adding to what sammitch says, you're trying to send two mails so check both messages

Comment: so what happened here? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code modifying the data from forms and it works. The error **does not come from syntax** as you suspected

My guess would be : your **sendmail** is either broken or a wrong path (/usr/sbin/sendmail).  If you are working in your own server check your sendmail path using

> phpinfo()

And if it's a hosting service (I understand this is your case) then contact support, since this is a server issue.

If you have ssh acces to such hosting service, access it and execute your script using:

```
php -q *[yourScript.php]*
```

Together with the error reporting and it may give you a trace to what's happening with the bin files